# How to avoid Segmentation fault: 11; c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm debugging a simple C++ script using gdb and see that I get an error when I try and initialize `temp_grid`. I try and compile it by running

```
g++ -Wall initial.cc -o initial
```

Is there a way to avoid this segmentation fault with something inside the script?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <valarray>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  using std::array;
  array<array<float, 1024>, 1024> grid ={};

  // temp grid
  array<array<float, 1024>, 1024> temp_grid ={};

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: and you have overflowed the stack. Do not create large object as local variable!

Comment: You overflowed the stack. Welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 5):

You are most likely overflowing the stack, which has relatively limited storage space for local variables. Try allocating them using dynamic storage (using `new`). For maximum robustness, use smart pointers (`unique_ptr`) to manage the pointers.